# Add criteria coefficients to Neo4j SDN method/Cypher query

Tags: neo4j, cypher, spring-data-neo4j

I need to introduce criteria coefficients to the following SDN repository method with a Neo4j Cypher query:

```
@Query("MATCH ... ->(c) WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} WITH ... vg.avgVotesWeight as weight RETURN sum(weight) as weight")
List<WeightedDecision> getChildDecisions(@Param("decisionId") Long decisionId, @Param("criteriaIds") List<Long> criteriaIds);
```

in order to implement something like this:

```
MATCH ... ->(c) 
WHERE id(c) IN {criteriaIds} 
WITH ... (vg.avgVotesWeight * cCoefficient) as weight 
RETURN sum(weight) as weight
```

where `cCoefficient` is a coefficient for a certain criterion in `criteriaIds` list. So, together with a `criteriaIds` list I'd like to pass into the query a list of criteria coefficients.

Сoefficients are not mandatory. For example one of the criteria from `criteriaIds` list can have coefficient but another one - no.

Right now I don't know how to pass these coefficient parameters(for all or for some criteria in `criteriaIds` list) to my method and bind it to a query.

Is it possible with Neo4j/SDN/Cypher ? If so, please show an example.

**UPDATED**

After Michael's recommendations I got it working with a following syntax:

```
.... (vg.avgVotesWeight * (CASE WHEN c IS NOT NULL THEN coalesce({coefficients}[''+id(c)], 1.0) ELSE 1.0 END)) as weight ....
```

1. I need to check that `c` is not null so I'm using CASE statement
2. I need to cast long `id(c)` to String `''+id(c)` otherwise it fails with a following exception:

   nested exception is org.neo4j.cypher.CypherTypeException: Expected 138 to be a java.lang.String, but it was a java.lang.Long

Also, I have to pass `Map<String, Double> coefficients` instead of `Map<Long, Double> coefficients` into my SDN method.

Is any way to optimize this approach ? For example avoid type casting or/and implement null pointer validation in a more elegant way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should be able to pass in a map where the coefficients are keyed.

For ones that don't exist you can use defaults with

`coalesce({coefficients}.foo, 1.0)`

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do I need to pass criteriaId and coefficient as a Key/Value in a single map or as a separated parameters ? And also what is ".foo" ?

Comment: Ok, I got it.. "foo" is a key where coefficient is a value.. But how to use multiple coefficients for different criteriaIds ? How to use for example criteriaId as a key in this Cypjher query ?

Comment: I mean for example `coalesce({coefficients}.id(c), 1.0)` or something like that... right now I can't get it working.

Comment: I got it working.. I have updated my question and added my current implementation. Is any way to optimize this ? Thanks.